# Programa en c no realiza división correctamente

Tags: c, division

Me acabo de encontrar con un problema al realizar un programa en c el cuál jamás había visto, las divisiones fraccionarias no las realiza de manera correcta por ejemplo este pequeño código:

```
float aux = 65 / 30;
printf("%f\n", aux);

salida >>> 2.000000
```

y si lo hago de manera directa:

```
printf("%f\n", 65 / 30);

salida >>> 0.000000
```

¿Qué puede ser? y ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Estas trabajando con números enteros. Si quieres que se traten como *flotantes*, cambialos a `65.0 / 30.0;`

Comment: Entiendo que te de un 2 en el primer caso ya que esta haciendo la división entera al encontrarse dos enteros como operandos. Pero si que me parece curioso que en el segundo caso te escriba 0. ¿Alguien sabe por qué escribe 0 en lugar de 2? En cualquier caso ya te han dado la respuesta, usar números en coma flotante. He hecho una prueba y casteando a (float) también obtienes 2.166667: `(float) 65/30`

Comment: `printf("%f\n", 65 / 30);` está mal. [Manifestación](https://godbolt.org/z/bEdhb3) Siempre utiliza las opciones de advertencia de tu compilador, como se muestra.

Comment: @ordago En el segundo caso, `65 / 30` es una operación entera. Sin embargo, está usando el indicador `%f`, que necesita un valor en coma flotante. Eso es un comportamiento indefinido. Tal como se comentó en su día, si usara números flotantes no tendría ese problema: `printf( "%f\n", 65.0f / 30.0f );`

Comment: @Juanjo gracias por la aclaración :)